# show Hide Toolbar Items

Tags: extjs, toolbar, extjs6

I have a toolbar having one button as follows

```
{ text: 'Save', tooltip: 'Save report', iconCls: 'some-cls', handler: 'somehandler' }
```

I want to hide this button for some condition.

for this I am getting toolbar items and hide/show the items as follows.

```
showHideToolbarItems: function(titles)
{
    tbarItems = getToolbarItems(); // Getting items successfully
    for (var i = 0, len = tbarItems.count; i < len; i++) {
        var item = tbarItems.itemAt(i);
        if (titles.indexOf(item.text) > -1)
        {
            item.setVisible(false); 
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this function as `showHideToolbarItems(['Save']);`
But I am getting error **setvisible is not a function.**

What I am doing wrong here

Comment: Hello Microsoft DN

Comment: what is your extjs version?

Comment: Please provide a proper code in fidller i check your mistake in fiddler

Comment: What is `getToolbarItems`. What type does it return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add reference to your button for faster access and right approach

```
{ 
    text: 'Save',
    reference: 'saveBtn',
    tooltip: 'Save report',
    iconCls: 'some-cls',
    handler: 'somehandler'
}
```

and inside your viewController:

```
showHideToolbarItems: function(titles)
{
    var view = this.getView(),
        saveButton = view.lookupReference('saveBtn');

        saveButton.hide();
        //saveButton.show();
}
```